# Что означает интерфейс в этом определении

Tags: python, django

Читаю документацию по Django и не могу понять, что означает здесь слово интерфейс, насколько я знаю в Python их нет

> Manager - это интерфейс, через который для моделей Django предоставляются операции запросов к базе данных. По крайней мере, один Manager существует для каждой модели в приложении Django.

Можете объяснить простыми словами что здесь означает слово интерфейс? Лично я понимаю слово интерфейс как какие-то общие методы доступные разным типам объектов

Comment: Думаю, здесь имеется в виду кухонно-бытовой смысл, что интерфейс — это просто способ взаимодействия. В общем не берите в голову, Manager это просто такой объект с методами, которые позволяют удобно создавать объекты QuerySet

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо Вам большое